# Is there any other way for this procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have 7 fields in a table; possible combinations of fields generate some result. A combination can be 1 or 4 or 7 or all and so on, which can be changed dynamically as given by client. I have to create a procedure for it. These fields are BIT type. Is there any other way to create these procedures except defining for each case by If Else...If Else?

```
@Chk_title AS BIT ,
@Chk_Description AS Bit ,
@Chk_Keywords AS BIT,
@Chk_Category AS BIT,
@Chk_Location AS BIT,
@Chk_Source AS BIT,
@Chk_Date AS BIT,
@RD_btn_AND_OR AS BIT

AS

if @RD_btn_AND_OR = 1
Begin
    if  @Chk_title = 1 AND @Chk_Description=1 AND @Chk_Keywords=1 @Chk_Category=1 @ Location=1 @ Chk_Source=1 @Chk_Date=1
        Begin
        Select title, Description, Keywords, category, Location, source, Date from server_des where title Like '%'+@title+'%' AND Description  Like '%'+@Description+'%' AND Keywords Like '%'+@Keywords+'%' AND category Like '%'+@Category+'%' AND Location Like '%'+@Location+'%'AND source Like '%'+@Source+'%' AND Date Like '%'+@Date+'%'
        End
     ELSE if  @Chk_title = 1 AND @Chk_Description = 1 AND @Chk_Keywords = 0 @Chk_Category=1 @ Location=1 @ Chk_Source=1 @Chk_Date=0
        Begin
        Select title, Description, null as'Keywords', category, Location, source, Date from server_des where title Like '%'+@title+'%' AND  Description  Like '%'+@Description+'%' AND category Like '%'+@Category+'%' AND Location Like '%'+@Location+'%' AND source Like '%'+@Source+'%' AND Date Like '%'+@Date+'%'
        End
     ELSE if @Chk_title=0 AND @Chk_Description=1 AND @Chk_Keywords=1  @Chk_Category=1 @ Location=1 @ Chk_Source=0 @Chk_Date=1
        Begin
        Select null as'Title', Description, Keywords, category, Location, source, Date from server_des where  Description  Like '%'+@Description+'%' AND  Keywords Like '%'+@Keywords+'%' AND category Like '%'@Category'%' AND Location Like '%'+@Location+'%' AND source Like '%'+@Source+'%' AND Date Like '%'+@Date+'%'
        End
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL - compose SQL command based on your data and run it. Like this:

```
@Chk_title AS BIT ,
@Chk_Description AS Bit ,
@Chk_Keywords AS BIT,
@Chk_Category AS BIT,
@Chk_Location AS BIT,
@Chk_Source AS BIT,
@Chk_Date AS BIT,
@RD_btn_AND_OR AS BIT

AS

DECLARE @cmdSQL VARCHAR(250)
SET @cmdSQL = 'Select'

if @RD_btn_AND_OR = 1
Begin
    if  @Chk_title <> 1
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' null as'
    SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' title,'
    if  @Chk_Description <> 1
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' null as'
    SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Description,'
    if  @Chk_Keywords <> 1
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' null as'
    SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Keywords,'
    if  @Chk_Category <> 1
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' null as'
    SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Category,'
    if  @Chk_Location <> 1
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' null as'
    SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Location,'
    if  @Chk_Source <> 1
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' null as'
    SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Source,'
    if  @Chk_Date <> 1
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' null as'
    SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Date'
End

SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' from server_des where title Like ''%''+@title+''%'' AND Description  Like ''%''+@Description+''%'' AND Keywords Like ''%''+@Keywords+''%'' AND category Like ''%''+@Category+''%'' AND Location Like ''%''+@Location+''%''AND source Like ''%''+@Source+''%'' AND Date Like ''%''+@Date+''%'''

EXEC(@cmdSQL)
END
```

Comment: @Serg- Hello I am new to this website so i dont know how to post question directly to you. I have posted new question related to this as i require formatting in it. can you solve the problem

Comment: @Aishna I think we can use SQL-server chat room - [it's here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33/sql-database). And there is [faq on using it](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @Serg Once again thank you. But I am not accessible to it as My Stackflow reputation is low for that application. Anyways Thanks

Comment: @Aishna Possibly you can see email or web site in my profile?

Answer (score 1):

You could put it all in one statement like this, but you should check to make sure the execution plan that gets created isn't significantly worse than your old solution (if performance is important for this stored proc):

```
SELECT title, Description, Keywords, category, Location, source, Date
FROM server_des
WHERE (@Chk_title <> 1 OR title LIKE '%'+@title+'%')
    AND (@Chk_Description <> 1 OR Description  LIKE '%'+@Description+'%')
    AND (@Chk_Keywords <> 1 OR Keywords Like '%'+@Keywords+'%')
    AND (@Chk_Category <> 1 OR category Like '%'+@Category+'%')
    AND (@Chk_Location <> 1 OR Location Like '%'+@Location+'%')
    AND (@Chk_Source <> 1 OR source Like '%'+@Source+'%')
    AND (@Chk_Data <> 1 OR Date Like '%'+@Date+'%)
```

Comment: I did not get what you mean by your this statement"check to make sure the execution plan that gets created isn't significantly worse than your old solution:"

Comment: SQL is a high level, non-procedural language. The actual steps that the server will take to perform your query are generated by a component call the query optimizer. Depending on your server settings the query optimizer may try to generate a plan that will be suitable for any set of input values which may result in poorer performance if a different set of values significantly change the amount of work required to satisfy the query.